# How can I preselect a file in windows explorer using .net?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-explorer

How can I popup a windows explorer on a specific folder with a specific file highlighted ?

I'm interested in solutions for XP, Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See *Explorer.exe Command-Line Options for Windows XP* at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853

`/select,<object>`  Opens a window view with the specified folder, file, or program selected.

Example 1: `Explorer /select,C:\TestDir\TestProg.exe` (Opens a window view with TestProg selected.)

Answer (score 7):

There's a "/select" switch in explorer.exe:

```
"/select,FileName"
```

You can use the Process.Start to execute it.